# Push first object to last in javascript array keeping all other values intact

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JavaScript array :

```
 var days = [
            {
                "day": "sunday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "monday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "tuesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "wenesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "thursday",
                "morning": "16:30 - 19:00 Uhr",
            },
            {
                "day": "friday",
                "morning": "09:00 - 18:00 Uhr",
            },
            {
                "day": "saturday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            }
        ];
```

How can i change the `0th index object` to last value in the array?

so my expected array will be like this :

```
 var days = [               
            {
                "day": "monday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "tuesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "wenesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            },
            {
                "day": "thursday",
                "morning": "16:30 - 19:00 Uhr",
            },
            {
                "day": "friday",
                "morning": "09:00 - 18:00 Uhr",
            },
            {
                "day": "saturday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            }, 
            {
                "day": "sunday",
                "morning": "geschlossen",
            }
        ];
```

I played around with splice and pop, but not getting anywhere intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use javascript `shift` and `push` function
`push` function adds the element in last and `shift` function removes and returns the first element

```
days.push(days.shift());
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the element from the beginning of the array. [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) does this. Then you need to add that element to the end of the array. [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does that. Since `shift` returns the element shifted, you can do it in one call:

```
days.push(days.shift());
```

The key functions for affecting the first and last elements of an array are:

- `shift`: remove an element from the beginning of the array
- `unshift`: add an element to the beginning of the array
- `pop`: remove an element from the end of the array
- `push`: add an element to the end of the array

Comment: Thankyou.. Worked perfectly.. Since all of you posted the same answer, i accepted the one with the lowest reputation..

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
days.unshift(days.pop())
```

EDIT, after op edit:

```
days.push(days.shift())
```

Comment: I want the popped out 0th index to be inserted at the last...:(

Comment: :) In cases like these, accept the answer from the guy(or gal) with the lowest reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this **(not tested)** :

```
var days= [
            {
                "day": "sunday",
                "morning": "geschlossen"
            },
            {
                "day": "monday",
                "morning": "geschlossen"
            },
            {
                "day": "tuesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen"
            },
            {
                "day": "wenesday",
                "morning": "geschlossen"
            },
            {
                "day": "thursday",
                "morning": "16:30 - 19:00 Uhr"
            },
            {
                "day": "friday",
                "morning": "09:00 - 18:00 Uhr"
            },
            {
                "day": "saturday",
                "morning": "geschlossen"
            }
        ];


var first = days[0];
days.shift();
days.push(first);
console.log(days);
```